# Assembly x86 reading kernel from NTFS filesystem disk

Tags: assembly, x86, disk, ntfs

I have made a bootloader in (x86) assembly and I want to call the kernel.bin (coded in assembly) located in the same disk as bootloader with NTFS filesystem. I have tried to use BIOS' int 0x13 but it can't read from a filesystem, only specific CHS address.

My bootloader till now is:

```
BITS 16
ORG 0x7C00

jmp short strt

strt:
    mov ah, 00h  ;function
    mov al, 12h  ;640x480 resolution + colors
    int 0x10
    jmp main
    
main:
    jmp main     ;infinity loop
    
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: Yeah, that's life. The BIOS doesn't know about NTFS (or any other filesystem for that matter).

Comment: Have fun writing your own NTFS filesystem driver, then.  The BIOS doesn't contain a filesystem driver!  Some open-source bootloaders like GRUB might have NTFS support, IDK.  The modern way for bootloaders to access filesystems is to make it a 64-bit UEFI application instead of a 16-bit legacy BIOS MBR boot sector.  The old-school way to deal with this is have GRUB stage1.5 in spare sectors between the partition table and a real partition, containing FS drivers.  And/or to embed a list of sectors into the MBR so it can find stuff to load next.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: The bootloader is 16bit in order to load quickly and the kernel will change it to 32bit. And how can I code my own NTFS filesystem in assembly (and fit in the bootloader)? (I suppose with int 0x13?)

Comment: @JimAntonopoulos: My guess is that you can't, and you would need a multi-stage bootloader: some mechanism to load a larger block of code from sectors that can be located without having to fully walk the filesystem.  For comparison, the Linux NTFS3 driver is 20,000 lines of C code.  This is a **big project** and probably not the first thing you want to embark on, when you're currently (as it appears) just at the level of writing "Hello world".

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: Yes, it sounds a little bit hard. But I don't have any way to call a kernel, in order to bypass the limit of 510 bytes.

Comment: So adjust your design goals.  It's your kernel, you get to decide what the on-disk format looks like.  You could for instance choose to reserve the first N sectors of the disk, where N is a large number that you pick, for the second-stage bootloader or the kernel itself.  You could decide to use FAT instead of NTFS for starters.  Or, switch to UEFI as already suggested.

Comment: Look at how GRUB is designed, especially where it installs its stage1.5 bootloaders.  (You might also want to look at older simpler GRUB versions, like GRUB 1.0.)  Or of course forget all this obsolete stuff and write a UEFI application that starts in 64-bit mode, so you can use the UEFI environment's support for the VFAT filesystem of the UEFI partition.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: I would try UEFI but the problem is that I don't have a real computer with UEFI support.

Comment: Virtual machines support them just fine, and you'll probably want to do almost all of your development on a VM anyway, as it'll make debugging much easier.  But if you do have a particular old non-UEFI machine that you eventually want to run on, then that's a design constraint that you get to live with.

Comment: `The bootloader is 16bit in order to load quickly` who said that it'll load faster? Modern UEFI can boot directly in 32 or 64-bit and are much faster

Comment: @phuclv: I don't have any computer that supports UEFI, so I am testing everything in Legacy BIOS.

Comment: then you have a legacy system, not modern at all